How to replace line in file with huge file content using shell
I need to replace line in file with content of another huge file. Is that really possible?
I tried
DATA=$(cat $logName)
gawk -i inplace -v r="$DATA" '{gsub("'"$line_to_replace"'",r)}1' file.txt

That was okay for relatively small files (up to 1581 lines), but the error Argument list too long occured for the file with ~7000 lines
Which command should I use instead?
p.s. I also tried sed "s/$line_to_replace/ $(<$DATA)/", but it didn't work at all. I got unterminated s' command

You are loading a whole file into a variable and then substituting variable with whole file's variable. So if you could show samples(not complete data only samples) then may be we could try to give better solution, cheers.

Also you can change your code to gawk -v r="$DATA" '{gsub("'"$line_to_replace"'",r)}1'  file.txt > tempFile && mv tempFile file.txt but then it defeats the purpose of using gawk since its already having inplace option in it.

Samples...That's an overcomplicated schema of getting general log file from different places.
I have the general file with special internal tags, where I insert name of logs. So $line_to_replace means something like "program1_utility1_logfile".
And the content I replaced with is the log file itself.
Gosh, maybe I should just use python or something instead...

I don't think it's a good idea to use your $line_to_replace as a regexp, unless that variable really is a regexp

Post the whole error message you got as I don't see anything in your code that could produce a "Argument list too long" message so it's hard to guess how to help you solve that problem.

Reading the huge file into a Bash variable is brittle and a waste of memory. sed already knows how to read another file.
sed -e "/$line_to_replace/!b" -e "r $logName" -e d

If $line_to_replace is not a regular expression, you will probably want to escape any regex special characters in the string. Also, if it contains a slash, use a different regex delimiter, or escape the slash.
If the intent is not to completely replace the entire line, you will need a slightly more complex script.
In very brief,

/.../!b says to skip the rest of the script if the current line doesn't match the regex.
r $logName says to read the contents of the file pointed to by the variable $logName
d removes the line we read as input. (If you leave the line, it will be left before the contents of the file.)

sed "s/foo/$bar/" breaks when $bar contains newlines, or literal slashes. You could escape all newlines and slashes in the data, too; but again, there should be no need in this scenario.
Interpolating shell variables with arbitrary contents into a sed script (or an Awk script, or a Python script, for that matter) is inherently brittle, but it can be done once you understand how this works.

Assuming that $line_to_replace and $logName can safely be used inside sed expressions

sed can be finicky, but the string after r could basically be anything within those bounds. The answer already contains a remark on regex specials in $line_to_replace, though I added a passage about slashes, too (thanks for prodding me).

I'm surprised about the r; does it handle a ; or \n in the filename?

That's probably implementation-specific. My MacOS sed handles a literal semicolon just fine. There appears to be no straightforward way to use a file name with a newline in it.

I could forge a few breaking cases using a semicolon in the filename with GNU sed; At the very least it needs a space after the semicolon for the next characters be interpreted as a new expression.

Thank you so much, it works!
Yeah, I replaced all unwanted slashes and so on in my $line_to_replace. I mentioned in one of the comments that this variable means path to file, which content I replace with. And it changes every time, because I have a list of such files in my target file.
Didn't know that this can be important for all of you, sorry.
"logName" files themselves had no problem, I didn't do anything with their content

@tripleee ln -s 'dodgy' safe; sed '...r safe...' file; rm safe ? one-shot: <'dodgy' sed '...r /dev/stdin...' file ?

use the ed (or) ex editor, example below using a here document and variables for the input,output and string to search for....
this loads ${infile}, searches for ${line2del}, deletes, reads ${bigfile} into ${infile}, writes a new file into ${outfile}, quits the original file -leaving it unchanged.
NB the lines immediately following the EOF are the output from the commands executed
ls -al *

line2del='/line 4'
infile=test.txt 
bigfile=bigfile.csv 
newfile=newfile.txt

ed <<_EOF_
> r ${infile}
> ${line2del}
> d
> r ${bigfile}
> w ${outfile}
> q
> _EOF_
79
line 4
379285991
379286063


ls -al "${infile}" "${bigfile}" "${outfile}"
-rw-r--r--@ 1 xxx  staff  379285991  1 Jun 21:31 bigfile.csv
-rw-r--r--  1 xxx  staff  379286063  6 Jun 11:25 newfile.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 xxx  staff         79  6 Jun 11:12 test.txt

obviously, you need to try this


need to replace line in file with content of another huge file(...)file with ~7000 lines

This sounds like task for Getline/File. Consider following example, let file.txt content be
Able
Baker
Charlie

and numbers.txt to hold numbers from 1 to 7000, one at each line, which was created as follows
seq 7000 > numbers.txt

and task is to replace line with Baker with content of numbers.txt then
awk -i inplace '/Baker/{while(getline<"numbers.txt"){print};next}{print}' file.txt

changes file.txt to
Able
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
(...)
6992
6993
6994
6995
6996
6997
6998
6999
7000
Charlie

where (...) denotes line skipped for brevity sake.
Explanation: for line containing Baker I repeat GetLine/File-print to output content of said file, then instruct GNU AWK to get next line, so current line will not be included. All other lines are just printed.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

while(getline<"numbers.txt") would go into an infinite loop if getline failed, it needs to be while( (getline<"numbers.txt") > 0) see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.
